# Passing in filter keywords | Python Tweepy API

Tags: python, api, tweepy

my first post here...
I'm trying to pass in multiple arguments for a Tweepy stream filter but it's pulling all tweets with ANY of these keywords. Suggestions to modify the below code to make sure pulled tweets contain ALL of these keywords? Thanks!

```
import tweepy
import login

exampleWords = ["Python", "Java", "C++"]

class myStream(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)

exampleStream = myStream(
    login.CONSUMER_KEY, login.CONSUMER_SECRET, 
    login.ACCESS_TOKEN, login.ACCESS_SECRET)

exampleStream.filter(track=exampleWords, languages=["en"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found it in the Twitter developer documentation:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query#list

code should be separated by a space, not a comma, so...

exampleWords = ["Python Java C++"]